# Blocking an ip address on a chain

Tags: iptables

I have the following iptables chain:

```
sudo iptables -N BLOCK24
sudo iptables -A BLOCK24 -m recent --name blocked --set
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 300 --hitcount 200 -j BLOCK24
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m recent --name blocked --rcheck --seconds 86400 -j BLOCK24
sudo iptables -A BLOCK24 -j LOG --log-prefix='[NETFILTER] ' --log-level 7
sudo iptables -A BLOCK24 -j REJECT
```

This blocks IPs for 24 hours when they request >= 200 connections in 300 seconds.

Is there anyway I can manually insert an IP into this chain? Something like?

```
iptables -A BLOCK24 -s 192.168.1.100 -j DROP
```

Comment: I bet fail2ban could be used to do this, not sure how to do it manually

Answer (score 2):

Like this: `echo +192.168.1.100 >/proc/net/xt_recent/blocked`, or if you need to sudo, `echo +192.168.1.100 | sudo tee /proc/net/xt_recent/blocked`

Source: [`man iptables-extensions`](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html)